# How do you sort struct members to a Queue in C?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

I have a struct called patients that needs to be organized. It should add a patient to the queue in the order given by their ID. However those with a greater number for severity can cut in front of the queue. The assignment I am working on requires us to use C and structs for the queue. The goal is to create an example of a Discrete-Event simulation.

I am not sure how to go about incorporating a struct. I have tried to look up code that uses structs, but all of them seem to use arrays. So far I have the basic implementation of FIFO.

For example, how can I use this struct I have created:

```
struct patients{
    int id;
    int severity;
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    char *state;
    double time_spent;
};
```

Have it enqueued to the queue by ID / adjusted by severity

```
ListNode* startPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    struct patients p1;
    struct patients p2;
    struct patients p3;
    struct patients p4;
    /*patient 1 specification */
    p1.id=1;
    p1.severity=2;
    p1.firstName="Joe";
    p1.lastName="C";
    p1.state="Patient has arrived";
    p1.time_spent = 0;
    /*patient 2 specification */
    p2.id=2;
    p2.severity=3;
    p2.firstName="Sam";
    p2.lastName="W";
    p2.state="Patient has arrived";
    p2.time_spent = 0;
    /*patient 3 specification */
    p3.id=3;
    p3.severity=2;
    p3.firstName="Mary";
    p3.lastName="L";
    p3.state="Patient has arrived";
    p3.time_spent = 0;
    enqueue(p1.id);
    enqueue(p2.id);
    enqueue(p3.id);
```

So given these specifications, I would want the queue to return the order as such: Sam (severity=3) -> Joe (Severity=2, but id=1) -> Mary (Severity=2, id=3)

```
void enqueue(ListNode* *startPtr, char value){
    ListNode* newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if(newPtr == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return;
    }
    newPtr->data = value;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    ListNode* currentPtr = *startPtr;
    //shifting current ptr until we find the last element
    while(currentPtr->nextPtr!=NULL){
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    //currentPtr is now the last Node of the queue
    currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the definition of `ListNode`? Also, the code which calls `enqueue()` isn't passing the right number of arguments. Thirdly, you're passing in the `id` which is an `int` but the 2 parameters to `enqueue()` are a `ListNode**` and a `char`, so it's unclear what this code is trying to do. Can you clarify?

Comment: Ah, that was the example I found to implement the enqueue. What I am really trying to do with this enqueue function is sort the structs by id/severity. However I dont know where to begin even as to what to include in the parameters. I just some guidance as to how to incorporate my struct i have created into the function

Comment: It sounds like you're asking what should go into the `ListNode` structure, is that correct?

Comment: I believe that's what I am trying to get at. Sorry for not being clear enough, but essentially I just need to somehow organize my struct patients I have created through its members (id & severity). After I get the enqueue it should make it easier for me to do the rest.

Comment: You may want to read up on a data structure called "priority queue".

Comment: @TrushPatel Looks like you have an answer! You can also check out [how other people have made linked lists and queues on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list+c). There are a lot of questions about linked lists because they come up a lot in introductory classes. There's some good advice over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass either a pointer to each structure into the enqueue function, or, if the patient structures are not persistent, the entire structure. You need to make sure the enqueue function has both the id and severity values for each patient so it can insert based on both.

```
enqueue(&p1);
```

OR

```
enqueue(p1);
```

The following *untested* code is going to assume you're passing a pointer to the enqueue function, since this is preferred if the structures are persistent.

Next, your enqueue function needs to insert FIRST based on severity, THEN based on id. Not the other way around, since the severity is used as the primary sort key, with the id being a secondary sort key. We can do this by iterating through the list until we find a severity that is not greater than the severity of the node to be inserted. If the severity is equal, then we need to continue iterating until we find an id that is greater than the id of the node to be inserted, or until the severity decreases. At this point, the insertion point has been found.

```
void enqueue(ListNode** startPtr, struct patients* p){
    ListNode* newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    if(newPtr == NULL){
        printf("Not enough memory");
        return;
    }

    newPtr->data = p;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    ListNode* currentPtr = *startPtr;

    //shifting current ptr until we find where severity is equal to the new node's severity 
    // AND until the id is larger than the following node
    // OR until the end of the list is reached
    while(currentPtr->nextPtr != NULL &&
        currentPtr->nextPtr->data->severity > p->severity ||
        (
            currentPtr->nextPtr->data->severity == p->severity && // the severity is the same, but the ids are out of order still
            currentPtr->nextPtr->data->id < p->id
        )
    ){
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    // currentPtr is now the node directly before the node to be inserted
    // now we insert newPtr into the list
    newPtr->next = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    currentPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
}
```

If you are passing the structure into the enqueue function not as a pointer, than you need to remember to allocate memory for the data. Also, this implementation could change depending on how you have your linked list implemented (either using a dummy head node or not)

Also remember to change the datatype of 'data' in your ListNode structure from an int to a struct patients*

Comment: Wow..thanks for the help! It was easy to follow the code and it cleared up the confusion as to what to have as my struct parameter. One question though, when calling the function what should I pass? Right now I have it as: enqueue(&p1); however it doesn't seem to work. (Dont know if this is because the code has been untested or if I am not passing it in correctly)

Comment: The enqueue function should also be given a pointer to the linked list head. That part of your program wasn't included in the original question, so I'm not sure exactly how you should pass it in, but I'm assuming something along the lines of enqueue(&headNode, &p1); where 'headNode' is a pointer to the first (probably dummy) node of your linked list.